# how to add animation in string

Tags: javascript, html

I want add rotation in my string for that i have set interval but its not getting me as i want. it works only for one time when i reload the browser. So what should i add for continuing the function.

this is my code 
HTML

```
<html> 
  <head>
  <title>JavaScript basic animation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="myfunction_2.js"></script>
  </head> <body onload="shubham()">
  <div id="target">w3resource</div>


<button >click</button>

  </body> 
  </html>
```

javascript

```
function shubham() 
{
var x=document.getElementById('target').textContent;

var y=x.split('');

var z=y[0];

var m=y[y.length-1];

setInterval(function () 
{
 document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = m+x.substring(0,8);
},500);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code was that the variables were initialized once, and whenever, the setInterval function was called, there was no change in variables and hence the result remained the same which appeared as function only executed 1 time only.

Move your variables inside the **setInterval** function.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var x = document.getElementById('target').textContent;

  var y = x.split('');

  var z = y[0];

  var m = y[y.length - 1];
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = m + x.substring(0, 8);
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="target">w3resource</div>
```

Comment: @naresh - Welcome mate :)

Comment: Also it's best to use `y.length - 1` on your substring to make it account for other string lengths.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this

```
<html>

<head>
<title>JavaScript basic animation</title>
</head>

<body onload="shubham()">
<div id="target">w3resource</div>
<button onclick="shubham()">click</button>
</body>

</html>
<script>
function shubham() {
    var x = document.getElementById('target').textContent;
    var y = x.split('');
    var z = y[0];
    var m = y[y.length - 1];
    setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = m + x.substring(0, 8);
    }, 500);
 }
 </script>
```